# while loop fundamentals thirteens.cpp

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the output starts from 13 in the following program.  I want to understand the change of value in counter and why it outputs 13 first.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 100)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 13 == 0 ){
            cout << counter << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%` *"modulo"* operator returns the remainder of the division of `counter / 13` and output only occurs when that equals `0` -- which means only multiples of `13` -- and `counter == 1` on the first iteration so `0` is never output.. [C11 Standard - 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators(p5)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p5)

Comment: Anass Sbiyyaa, "I don't understand why the output starts from 13 in the following program." What were you expecting?

Comment: What do you think it should have started from?

Comment: I got it, it's until the thirteenth time through the loop that if condition is true and counter == 13 which is the first output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two operators for integer division...
'/' gives you the number of times the right hand operand goes into the left hand operand

'%' gives you the remainder when the right hand operand can no longer go into the left hand operand

You are using modulus division '%'.

Your first time through the loop:

- right hand is 13
- left hand is 1
- 1 divided by 13 is: 0 remainder 1
- 1 != 0 so no console output

Your second time through the loop:

- right hand is 13
- left hand is 2
- 2 divided by 13 is: 0 remainder 2
- 2 != 0 so no console output

Your thirteenth time through the loop:

- right hand is 13
- left hand is 13
- 13 divided by 13 is: 1 remainder 0
- 0 = 0 , console output of current counter which is 13

You will only get console output when 13 can go into the counter multiple times, with no remainder.

Comment: This explanation is confusing, and also wrong.  The simple fact is on the first iteration, `counter` is 1 at the time the if-statement is evaluated.  Thus `counter % 13` is 1, which is not equal to 0.  To be utterly clear, your assertion that `0 % 13 == 13` is incorrect. `X % N` can _never_ equal `N`.

Comment: too true... its been a long day...  i reformatted to make it more clear and corrected my math.  core of the answer is correct though.... you only get output when counter is a multiple of 13

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself: What is the first number that divided by 13 gives rest equal 0?
Notice that incrementatnion is before conditional statement. So, for first iteration counter is equal 1 for conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

'%' operator gives the remainder of a division operation. So any number from 1 to 99 which will we be divisible with 13 will be printed(not 0, because you are incrementing counter as soon as the loop starts, so 0 value doesn't enter the if statement).

If you want to check for 0 too, put counter++ after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 100)
{
    counter++;
    count<<counter<<endl;
}
```

This code will show the values of **counter** from 1 to 100. 
But as you have added a condition of `counter % 13 == 0`, it means that the value of **counter** will be shown only if **counter** is divisible by 13. In other words, the only multiples of 13 up to 100 will be shown in the output.

> PS: **'%'** is a modular operator. `A % B` equals to `A - (floor(A/B)*B)`